# Excel VBA if user hides row shift data up? Using Worksheet_Change

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple tables in my worksheet (this being the second worksheet and data is input into the worksheet off of the main page via cell formulas).  I am attempting to write a Worksheet change macro that upon hiding a row it shifts the cells up and maintains the overall height of the table.

The screen shot has the before and after results of what I am attempting.  So on the left if row 13 is hidden the macro would move the first subrow in table 2 up to the last row in table 1 and table 2 would resize to 7 total  rows.  My sheets have a variable number of tables (typically 2-10 tables), so I will attempt to make it dynamic.

If you can assist or point me in the direction of a similar answer that is greatly appreciated. My main difficulty is creating the statement if the row is hidden, once I have completed that I can go after the formatting.  Thanks so much for your time and efforts.

Comment: "hiding" a row does not invoke the `Worksheet_Change` event.  Also, your question does not include any screenshots.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My main difficulty is creating the statement if the row is hidden

Where `r` is a `Range` object:

```
If r.EntireRow.Hidden Then
    ' Do something if the row is hidden
Else:
    ' Do something else if the row is not hidden
End If
```